# Stop event propagation in canvas with paper.js over reveal.js

Tags: javascript, ipad, canvas, paperjs, reveal.js

I'm using Reveal.js to make a presentation in ipad, but I want to add a canvas interaction with Paper.js, I used this example http://paperjs.org/examples/meta-balls/ and works, but when I drag canvas Revealjs makes an slide change.

Some one know if can I stop drag event propagation? or can I exclude canvas for Reveal.js?. Thanks a Lot.

Comment: It might be worth adding a small extract of sample code to your question rather than a link, as those can be moved or deleted in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration for Reveal.js is to recognize touch input on mobile devices. If you want to turn touch input off for a particular slide / event, call:

```
Reveal.configure({touch: false});
```